# TypeError: Type String Memory is not implicitly convertable to expected type adress

Tags: solidity, remix

I see the following error:

> TypeError: Type String Memory is not implicitly convertable to
> expected type adress while trying to execute

with the following code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.18 <0.5.13;

contract KYC {
   struct Customer { 
      string userName;
      string customerData;
      address Bank;
   }
   mapping (address => Customer) customers;
   address[] public customersArray;
   
 struct Bank { 
      string Name;
      address ethAddress;
      string regNumber;
   }
   mapping (address => Bank) bank;
   address[] public banksArray;
   
   
    function addCustomer (address _address, string memory _userName, string memory _customerData, address _bank) public {
        Customer storage customer = customers[_address];
        
        customer.userName=_userName;
        customer.customerData=_customerData;
        customer.Bank=_bank;
        
        customersArray.push(_address) -1;
    }
    
   function getCustomer(string memory uName) view public returns (string memory) {
        Customer storage customer = customers[uName];
        return customer.customerData;
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this line `Customer storage customer = customers[uName];` Your customers mapping maps address to the Customer struct whereas you are trying to map a the string uName to the struct. There are different ways you can receive customer data.

1. Get an address as a function parameter and return the name of the customer at this address.
2. Use `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2` and return the struct based on the address.

   ```
   function getCustomer(address _address) view public returns (Customer memory) {

        return customers[_address]; 

   }
   ```